# Fix Beginning of Time Series Plot - It Is Wildly Distorted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, rolling-computation

[image: Rolling Sharpe Ratio]Regardless of the time frame I put on this chart (i.e. 10yrs, 20yrs, 25yrs), the data in the beginning is always distorted -- i.e. very high or very low -- on the chart.

I thought it was a min_periods issue, but that doesn't seem to be it.

Appreciate any insight!

Tried making sure that there were no N/As in the calculation columns.

Tried changing min_periods to be larger.

No change.

What's charted on the bottom subplot is sharpe_rf in the code below.

```
asset1          = 'XLY Equity'
asset2          = 'USGG10YR Index'

#-------------Dataframe 1: Price Data from Multiple Securities-------------#
sids            = mgr[asset1, asset2]
d               = sids.get_historical(prices,start=startD,end=endD)
df              = pd.DataFrame(d)
df              = df.dropna()

df.columns      = ['Asset', 'Risk Free Rate']

#------------Returns and Standard Deviation---------------#
log_return          = np.log(df['Asset']) - np.log(df['Asset'].shift(1))
ten_day_return      = log_return.rolling(min_periods=10, window=30, center=False).sum()
std_20d             = df['Asset'].rolling(min_periods=10, window=30, center=False).std() 
max_std_today       = std_20d.max() - std_20d 

#------------Moving Averages------------#
ma_50               = df['Asset'].rolling(min_periods=10, window=50, center=False).mean()
ma_100              = df['Asset'].rolling(min_periods=10, window=100, center=False).mean()
ma_200              = df['Asset'].rolling(min_periods=10, window=200, center=False).mean()

# #------------Rolling Sharpe Ratio------------#
lookback            = 252
daily_returns       = log_return[1:]
std_returns         = daily_returns.rolling(min_periods=10,window=lookback,center=False).std()
std_returns         = std_returns.dropna()

avg_daily_return    = daily_returns.rolling(min_periods=10,window=lookback,center=False).mean()
avg_daily_return    = avg_daily_return.dropna()

sharpe              = avg_daily_return/std_returns
sharpe_final        = np.sqrt(252)*sharpe
sharpe_final        =sharpe_final.dropna()

sharpe_rf           = sharpe_final / df['Risk Free Rate']
sharpe_rf           = sharpe_rf.dropna()`
```

Comment: Please create a [reprex], including sample data in reproducible form (text, not a screenshot).